# How can I handle Gunicorn worker timeouts in my Flask application deployed on Railway?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, backend, gunicorn

I'm encountering an issue with Gunicorn workers timing out in my Flask application deployed on Railway. Here are the details:

Problem: Gunicorn workers are timing out shortly after starting, and the logs show "WORKER TIMEOUT."

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()
script.js:174 Error fetching model answer: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

I need assistance in resolving this issue and understanding the possible causes.

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('user_input', fullUserInput);

    fetch('/gpt3', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        // Extract the content from the data received
        let content = data.content;
        let overallScore = data.overall_score;
        let overallScoreElement = document.getElementById("overall-score");
        overallScoreElement.innerText = `${overallScore}`;

        // Display the result and hide the spinner
        spinnerDiv.style.display = 'none';
        content = content.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
        resultDiv.innerHTML = content;

        // Disable submit button after receiving the result
        submitBtn.disabled = true;
        enableButtons();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching response:", error);
        submitButtonClicked = false; // Reset the submit flag
      });
  });
```

this is my fetching code

```
@app.route('/gpt3', methods=['POST'])
def gpt3():
    user_input = request.form['user_input']
```

this is my part connecting with js